# What are the URL python pip will use to find the modules

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I need to install python3, pip, django and some other python modules in a system which has no access to internet as of now.
However, I will be given access for few really required urls for few days. I need to raise a firewall requests for those URLs. Please help with the list of urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open up your firewall to the download locations of all the packages you need to install.

PyPI is a metadata service that also provides storage for indexed packages. But it is not necessary that the package will be hosted on PyPI, the download location could be anywhere on the internet.

As a start open pypi.python.org, and as individual installations fail you can check the PyPI page for the correct download location and add it to your firewall.

As an alternative to this you can also setup your own PyPI [mirror](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.eggproxy)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Firewall requests takes me at least 3 days and have to go for all approval process, that's why I can't afford many fails during instalation process

Comment: Then maybe front load the effort of identifying all the packages you need by setting up the application and dependencies on a venv. And see where they all are hosted via the PyPI page. Or setup your own PyPI mirror that your server behind the firewall can talk to